# Not able to populate db to run cucumber scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, scenarios

I'm learning Cucumber, and I have to populate the db to run the scenarios.

These are the instructions:

> (...) you will create a step definition that will match the step
> `Given the following movies exist` in the `Background` section of both
> `sort_movie_list.feature` and `filter_movie_list.feature`. (Later in
> the course, we will show how to DRY out the repeated `Background`
> sections in the two feature files.)
>
> Add your code in the `movie_steps.rb` step definition file.  You can
> just use ActiveRecord calls to directly add movies to the database;
> it`s OK to bypass the GUI associated with creating new movies, since
> that's not what these scenarios are testing.

This one of the `*.feature` files

```
Feature: display list of movies filtered by MPAA rating
 
     As a concerned parent
      So that I can quickly browse movies appropriate for my family
      I want to see movies matching only certain MPAA ratings
    
    Background: movies have been added to database
    
      Given the following movies exist:
      | title                   | rating | release_date |
      | Aladdin                 | G      | 25-Nov-1992  |
      | The Terminator          | R      | 26-Oct-1984  |
      | When Harry Met Sally    | R      | 21-Jul-1989  |
      | The Help                | PG-13  | 10-Aug-2011  |
      | Chocolat                | PG-13  | 5-Jan-2001   |
      | Amelie                  | R      | 25-Apr-2001  |
      | 2001: A Space Odyssey   | G      | 6-Apr-1968   |
      | The Incredibles         | PG     | 5-Nov-2004   |
      | Raiders of the Lost Ark | PG     | 12-Jun-1981  |
      | Chicken Run             | G      | 21-Jun-2000  |
```

This is my code from `*_steps.rb`:

```
Given /the following movies exist/ do |movies_table|
  movies_table.hashes.each do |movie|
    Movie.create!(movie)
  end
  fail "Unimplemented"
end
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Background: movies have been added to database # features/sort_movie_list.feature:7
    Given the following movies exist:            # features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:3
      | title                   | rating | release_date |
      | Aladdin                 | G      | 25-Nov-1992  |
      | The Terminator          | R      | 26-Oct-1984  |
      | When Harry Met Sally    | R      | 21-Jul-1989  |
      | The Help                | PG-13  | 10-Aug-2011  |
      | Chocolat                | PG-13  | 5-Jan-2001   |
      | Amelie                  | R      | 25-Apr-2001  |
      | 2001: A Space Odyssey   | G      | 6-Apr-1968   |
      | The Incredibles         | PG     | 5-Nov-2004   |
      | Raiders of the Lost Ark | PG     | 12-Jun-1981  |
      | Chicken Run             | G      | 21-Jun-2000  |
      Unimplemented (RuntimeError)
      ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:7:in `/the following movies exist/'
      features/sort_movie_list.feature:9:in `Given the following movies exist:'
```

I have tried `movie = Movie.create!,  Movie.create!(movie), Movie.create! movie, movie = Movie.create!` (this last one just for pure desperation)... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My money is on colon (`:`) that you missed in your regex.

Comment: What regex? `movie` is a variable representing a hash

Comment: You have the step "Given the following movies exist:" and then you try to match it with "Given /the following movies exist/ do |movies_table|". Where is the `:` in the regular expression you are using to match the step definition?

Comment: Does it need regex? These syntax was already in the exercise, I'm supposed to write only the block after |movie|... Also I just checked Cucumber documentation, and I see examples with tables and no regex https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions

Comment: Correction: "Does it need `:` the regex?

Comment: Just try it and see if that helps. You can always change it back if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.

You iterate over the movies and then just before the `end` you do `fail "Unimplemented"`. What would you expect?

Comment: Thank you, it's the first time I use cucumber and I see `fail`. Since the code was given and I thought I was supposed to write in the block, I assumed `fail` was there for reason I will learn eventually.

Comment: This `fail` is there to indicate the feature not yet ready I guess